# Cloud callout with large aspect ratio

Tags: callout, cloud

I'm trying to use a cloud callout to remember people in a beamer presentation on a previous equation. Since the equation is long, I have to use a large aspect ratio for the callout, which results in a strange shape. Is there a way to change the shape of the cloud callout apart from changing the aspect ratio (i.e. changing height and width separately?).

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts,tikzmark}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Frame with some text, some items and a long formula, part of which should remind people on a previous formula
\begin{itemize}
\item first item
\item second item
\item third item
\item fourth item
\item fifth item
\item sixth item
\end{itemize}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\dot{f}(x,y)=&a \sin(x) \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}-\left(2xy+b+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}\cos(y)\right) \frac{\partial{f}(x,y)}{\partial y} +x^3-y^2\\
&\alert{-\frac{y}{2}\left(y-\frac{x^2}{y^2}\right)\frac{\partial^2{f}(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y}}
\end{split} \nonumber
\end{equation}
\pause
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{current page}{center}}
\node[cloud callout,draw,thick,fill=cyan,cloud puffs=50,cloud puff arc=100,callout relative pointer=(270:2cm),align=center,anchor=center,aspect=8] at (0,3) {$\dot g(x,y)=a \sin(x) \frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y}-\left(2xy+b+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}\cos(y)\right) \frac{\partial{g}(x,y)}{\partial y} +x^3-y^2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As you can see the cloud is larger than the frame, even though the equation fits into the frame. Can I make the left and right sides of the cloud callout somehow steeper? Would it also be possible to make the two little ellipses (the pointer?) more round?

Edit: my goal would be like this:
[image: goal]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts,tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
Frame with some text, some items and a long formula, part of which should remind people on a previous formula
\begin{itemize}
\item first item
\item second item
\item third item
\item fourth item
\item fifth item
\item sixth item
\end{itemize}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\dot{f}(x,y)& = a \sin(x) 
                \frac{\partial f(x,y)}
                     {\partial y} - 
                \left(2xy+b+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}\cos(y)\right) 
                \frac{\partial{f}(x,y)}
                     {\partial y} +x^3-y^2  \\
            &\qquad \alert{-\frac{y}{2}
                    \left(y-\frac{x^2}{y^2}\right)
                    \frac{\partial^2{f}(x,y)}
                         {\partial x \partial y}}
\end{split} \nonumber
\end{equation}
\pause
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{current page}{center}}
\node[cloud callout,cloud puffs=50,cloud puff arc=100,
      callout relative pointer=(240:3cm),
      callout pointer segments=3, % added
      draw,thick, fill=cyan, 
      %fill opacity=0.9, text opacity=1, % if you like to see background text
      align=center, anchor=center, 
      aspect=7, % changed
      inner xsep=-4em % <--- negative inner ysep
      ] at (1,3) {$\dot g(x,y)=a \sin(x) \frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y}-\left(2xy+b+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}\cos(y)\right) \frac{\partial{g}(x,y)}{\partial y} +x^3-y^2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Nice, I should have thought of that!

Comment: almost, I guess inner xsep and inner ysep was what I was looking for. Now I just want to change the shape of the three little bubbles, they should havel less eccentricity

Comment: Okay, I managed to do this by setting aspect=4 (changes also the shape of the little bubbles) and then adjusting inner xsep for the shape of the cloud.